# Setting standard deviation to 1 in PCA

Tags: variance, pca, standardization

I was going through Introduction to Statistical Learning in R, Seventh Printing, and I have a question about Principal Components Analysis. If the first principal component is measured as the direction along which the data set varies the most, then shouldn't the data set represented in page 381 - where as occurrences among 100,000 people, Assault has the highest variance - have a first principal component with a large dependence on Assault over Murder and Rape? I understood that setting all the variables to the same scale is important, but isn't setting the standard deviation to 1, leading us to unfairly prioritize variables with relatively lower absolute variance of variables in the same scale? Like in the USArrests data set provided, Murder has a variance of 18.97, Rape 87.73, and Assault 6945.16 on the same scale. So shouldn't the first component be mostly dependent on Assault, given that the data varies most along this variable?

Essentially, my point is that setting the standard deviation equal for all variables should mean that the variance for each variable is then set to nearly equal.

Comment: Welcome to CV.  We have many threads that focus on this very issue: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=pca+correlation+covariance+score%3A1

Comment: Yeah I checked those questions, too, but either I didn't understand it right, or this particular example I mentioned was wrong.